# How to pass path of selected file from Finder to Automator Shell script

Tags: finder, automator, zip

I am creating Automator Service to unzip selected files in the same folder they are located.

How can I get selected file absolute path in Automator, so I can pass it into my shell script ?

As you can see I am only passing filename for now, but its not unzipping in same folder.

I would like to change folder before `unzip`, and then execute `unzip`. I tried `cd ~` but it unzips to my homefolder. I would like to `unzip` in same folder as selected files exists.

[image]

Comment: Add `cd "$(dirname "$f")"` before the `unzip` line.

Comment: that is awesome, put it as answer pls and i mark it. thx a lot

Comment: I don't see why you need a script - I double-click on a zip file and it gets extracted into the same location with no other dialogue box or anything.

Comment: @SolarMike ArchiveUtility sometimes wont work for particular archive files and returning errors. Using unzip works as charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `cd "$(dirname "$f")"` before the `unzip` line.

```
for f in "$@"; do
    cd "$(dirname "$f")"
    unzip -o "$f"
done
```

or without changing to the directory, use the `-d` option

```
[-d exdir]
          An  optional  directory  to which to extract files.  By default, all files and subdirectories
          are recreated in the current directory; the -d  option  allows  extraction  in  an  arbitrary
          directory.....



for f in "$@"; do
    unzip "$f" -d "$(dirname "$f")"
done
```